# How can I change the type of field using <lightning:inputField> aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, inputfield

How can I change the type of field using `<lightning:inputField>` aura component?

For example, I create a custom picklist of strings field at Salesforce and I have to show them on aura component using `<lightning:inputField>`. But I desire to show this field in a radio button format.

How can I do that mantain the tag `<lightning:inputField>`.

Comment: Hi Debora, use the [lightning:radioGroup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:radioGroup/example) component.

Comment: Hello , but if I use lightning:radioGroup I have to manually set the values on a aura:attribute correct ? The problem is, constantly I have to add a new values in this variable which the tag lightning:inputField don´t have this problem because she takes dinamically those values on field of salesforce.

Comment: You can write code to populate automatically. Basically if you want to do something non-standard you are responsible to implement it.